# How to make multiple line charts in Python (or use facet charts)?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = {'website': ['google','google','google','google','google','google','google','google','google','google','google','google',
                       'facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook', 
                       'youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube'], 
    'values': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36],
     'month': ['january','january','january','january','january','january','january','january','january','january','january','january', 
              'january','january','january','january','january','january','january','january','january','january','january','january',
              'january','january','january','january','january','january','january','january','january','january','january','january'],
          'date': ['01-01-2000','02-01-2000','03-01-2000','04-01-2000','05-01-2000',
'06-01-2000','07-01-2000','08-01-2000','09-01-2000','10-01-2000',
'11-01-2000','12-01-2000','01-01-2000','02-01-2000','03-01-2000','04-01-2000','05-01-2000',
'06-01-2000','07-01-2000','08-01-2000','09-01-2000','10-01-2000',
'11-01-2000','12-01-2000','01-01-2000','02-01-2000','03-01-2000','04-01-2000','05-01-2000',
'06-01-2000','07-01-2000','08-01-2000','09-01-2000','10-01-2000',
'11-01-2000','12-01-2000']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I'm trying to make multiple time series plots for the data above but facetted by month.

So the Y-Axis = values and X-Axis = date for each time series plot

But each sub plot is done by the month column

And on each plot you can see multiple line charts which represent the websites

Something like this:

[image: plot split by month - time series]

I have used both facet_grid from seaborn sns and plotly express but seem to be getting stuck.

I have shown only 6 months here for the plot but it will be 12 months and the colours represent each of the websites -> so 3 lines google, facebook and youtube

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time",  row="sex")
g.map(sns.scatterplot, "total_bill", "tip")
```

Comment: Show your code. [ask] and [mre]

Comment: I have added my code

Comment: No you have not. "I have used both facet_grid from seaborn sns and plotly express but seem to be getting stuck." where are those sns and plotly attempts?

Comment: @Julien I have now - check again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [seaborn.relplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) for this. Consider the following dataframe:

```
month = np.random.choice(['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 
                          'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'], 36, 
                         p = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(12), size = 1)[0])
date = pd.date_range('20000101', periods = 36)
website = ['google','google','google','google','google','google','google','google','google','google','google','google',  
           'facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook','facebook',  
           'youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube','youtube']
values = np.random.randint(10, 30, 36)


df = pd.DataFrame({'website': website, 'values': values, 'month': month, 'date': date})
df.head()
```

```
  website  values     month       date
0  google      23   October 2000-01-01
1  google      13  November 2000-01-02
2  google      22     March 2000-01-03
3  google      25  February 2000-01-04
4  google      17   January 2000-01-05
```

Now illustrating it using `relplot` we get the following plot.

```
# Plot the lines on two facets
g = sns.relplot(
    data = df,
    x = "date", y = "values",
    hue = "website", col = "month",
    kind = "line", col_wrap = 3)

g.set_xticklabels(rotation = 90)
```

[image: using-relplot.png]